# Aligned two headerbox at the bottom

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, baposter

I am preparing my conference poster. I have three `\headerbox` that I need to align it at the bottom.
Sorry, I can post just a part  of the code.

```
\headerbox{Results}{name=Results,column=2,span=2,row=1,below=…}{
}

\headerbox{FUTURE RESEARCH}{name=FUTURE RESEARCH,column=0,above=bottom,below=…}{
}
\headerbox{Contact}{name= Contact,column=1,span=1,aligned=FUTURE RESEARCH,below=...,above=bottom}{

}
```

see this results:
[image]

I need to align the three box at the bottom. thanks to help me!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

I find the solution. I have to add `bottomaligned=Results` in the second and the third box.
and I delete above=bottom in both box.

```
\headerbox{Results}{name=Results,column=2,span=2,row=1,below=…}{
}

\headerbox{FUTURE RESEARCH}{name=FUTURE RESEARCH,column=0,bottomaligned=Results,below=…}{
}
\headerbox{Contact}{name= Contact,column=1,span=1,aligned=FUTURE RESEARCH,below=...,bottomaligned=Results}{

}
```

[image]